# Memory map of a process in Linux

Tags: process, linux-kernel, memory-mapping

I have the following code which I assembled and linked to get an executable out of it.

```
.data
```

hello:
    .ascii "Hello World"
.text

.global _start

_start:
    movl $4,%eax
    movl $1,%ebx
    movl $hello,%ecx
    movl $11,%edx
    int $0x80

```
movl $1,%eax
movl $0,%ebx
int $0x80
```

As a learning process, I want to look at the memory map of the process (by the above executable). Both pmap and cat /proc/PID/maps requires process id. If its a gcc compiled C program I can use gdb to have a breakpoint and get the pid in another terminal.

For the above case I'm not able to set any breakpoints as there is no debugger symbol table available in the executable. Is there any other way to see a process memory structure without using pid? I mean some kind of program which loads the executable and dump the memory structure.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the smartest way to do it but give it a try if it'll help you.

Write another program that `fork`s(save the child's pid) then let the child `exec` the executable you want to run.
There you go, you have the process id of the program to use `pmap` at some other terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Use `readelf` from GNU binutils to find the entry point in the ELF header, then tell `gdb` to put a breakpoint there.

```
$ readelf -h /bin/true
...
  Entry point address:               0x10000c5c
...
$ gdb /bin/true
...
(gdb) break *0x10000c5c
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10000c5c
(gdb) run
Starting program: /bin/true
...
Breakpoint 1, 0x10000c5c in ?? ()
(gdb) ^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 gdb /bin/true
$ ps
...
  744 tty1     00:00:00 true
...
$ less /proc/744/maps
```

This doesn't work with position-independent executables (PIE) because they get relocated to an unpredictable entry point. Look at the `Type:` line from `readelf -h`. If it says `DYN (Shared object file)`, it's PIE. If it says `EXEC (Executable file)`, it's not PIE.